# What is the meaning of Abraham's name?

Tags: genesis, abraham, onomastics

[Genesis 17:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+17%3A5&version=NIV) (NIV) states:

> No longer will you be called Abram; your name will be Abraham, for I have made you a father of many nations.

The edition of the Bible that I'm reading has a footnote saying that *probably* Abraham means father of many.

Could someone provide an additional reference (religious and/or etymological) where the meaning of the name of Abraham is explained?

Comment: Abraham = Hyper-human

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [a variety of commentaries](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/17-5.htm) the name Abram means "high father" while Abraham means "Father of a multitude".  The reason it is only "probably" in your commentary is because the usage of the word *raham* is not clearly attested to in ancient Hebrew itself, but only in closely related languages.

*Ellicott's Commentary* explains it well, plus offers a couple alternative ideas:

> Abraham = Father of a multitude, “raham” being an Arabic word, perhaps current in Hebrew in ancient times. Another interpretation of Abram is that it is equivalent to Abi-aram, Father of Aram, or Syria. This too is an Arabic form, like Abimael in Genesis 10:28. By some commentators the stress is thrown upon the insertion of the letter “h,” as being the representative of the name Yahveh or Yehveh.

Answer (score -1):

I study the Hebrew / Aramaic of the Bible. I do not allow or subscribe to the typographic-shift theories. The Hebrew text of the Bible should be read at its face value. We should not contaminate biblical Hebrew with European/Romance linguistic concepts. Read the Hebrew of the Bible as literal as possible, without apologising for it, nor inventing excuses for it.

Genesis 17:5

והיה שמך אברהם
כי אב המון גוים נתתיך

[אבר] = prominent organ/limb. Hence sometimes for referring to the wings of a bird. Hence sometimes for referring to the prominent organ of men.

[אברם] = perhaps plural.

[אברה] = participle/gerund. The state of being a prominent organ/limb.

[אברהם] = The gerund suffixed with 3rd person plural possessive = state of being their prominent-limb-organ.

Translation of the verse is:
Because I am giving/making you as of father of multitude of nations,
your name is no longer prominent-organs, but your name shall be being-their-prominent-organs.

Perhaps ...
Because I am giving/making you as of father of multitude of nations,
Your name is no longer just "foundations", but your name shall be be-their-foundations.